# How can I port forward with an airport extreme and a NAT enabled modem?

Tags: macbook-pro, port-forwarding, nat, airport-extreme

I run an Actiontec HD701D modem with NAT to an Airport extreme base station to laptop etc. As you might expect I get double NAT issues.

I tried a lot of different things to forward a port, but no luck.
Currently the airport is in bridge mode letting the modem handle the NAT, but still can't forward the port.

Also to note: firewall is off on the router, firewall is set to allow the application in OSX 10.6.3 and I did forward the port in the router. No luck.

Comment: Can you provide details about IP address assignment down the chain as well as the exact port forwarding rules you have in place down the chain?

Comment: You said you set the port forwarding in the *router*.  Since you have the router set to bridge mode and the modem is doing the NAT, you would need to forward the port in the *modem*'s configuration.  It should be at `http://192.168.0.1/`.  If you get the configuration for the AirPort at that address, you'll need to find its *LAN IP address* in the confiugration and change it to something like `192.168.0.200` so you can get through to the modem's configuration.